# Подсскажите что не так делаю!

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

Есть страница `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Выравнивание по центру</title>  
 </head>
 <body>
    <header>
       <a id="link-page-2">Link</a>
    </header>
    <section></section>
    <footer></footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Также есть 2 страница `page-2`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Выравнивание по центру</title>  
     </head>
     <body>
        <header>
           <a id="link-page-1">Link</a>
        </header>
        <section></section>
        <footer></footer>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Пытаюсь сделать **чтобы url не изменился** при переходе на новую страницу

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#link-page-1").click(function() {
           $("html").load("page2.html")
        });
    </script>

Подскажите, что не так делаю? И правильно так вообще делать?
Заранее спасибо
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсскажу (угу, мы наследники Слизерина :)):
[Хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/154617/).